# Why is Publisher splitting my document onto two pages?

Tags: printing, microsoft-publisher

I have a single-page document in Microsoft Publisher 2010. When I go to print it, however, it splits it into two pages, and I can't for the life of me figure out why or how to fix it. Since it is only one page, and as far as I can tell all the content fits well within the printable area, why is Publisher splitting it into two when I print, and how do I fix it?

In case my words are unclear, here's a picture. Here's how my document is set up (roughly) on the left, and what Publisher tries to do when I go to print it on the right.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was a stupid little thing. On the Print dialog, one of the options listed *should be* set to **One page per sheet**. In my case it had been set to **Tiled** for some reason. See picture below.

[image]